# how to apply varying gsub pattern (variable function) to each row of data.table in R

Tags: r, function, data.table, gsub, varying

I've got a data.table DT with a string column and a numeric column that indicates how many words from the start of the string should be extracted.

```
    > require(data.table)
    > DT <- data.table(string_col = c("A BB CCC", "DD EEE FFFF GDG", "AB DFD EFGD ABC DBC", "ABC DEF") 
                     , first_n_words = c(2, 3, 3, 1))
    > DT
                string_col first_n_words
    1:            A BB CCC             2
    2:     DD EEE FFFF GDG             3
    3: AB DFD EFGD ABC DBC             3
    4:             ABC DEF             1
```

I'd like to add a new column with the first-n-words of the string_col, as following:

```
> output_DT
            string_col first_n_words output_string_col
1:            A BB CCC             2              A BB
2:     DD EEE FFFF GDG             3       DD EEE FFFF
3: AB DFD EFGD ABC DBC             3       AB DFD EFGD
4:             ABC DEF             1               ABC
```

This is the gsub syntax that can be used:

```
> gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", first_n_words - 1, "}\\w+).*$"),"\\1", string_col)
```

I basically need to create this gsub function for every row, using first_n_words of that row before applying it to string_col of that row.
I'm only interested in a data.table syntax solution as it's a very large data set. a gsub solution would be most desired.

---

Edit: I've tried the following and it doesn't work

```
> DT[, output_string_col := gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", first_n_words - 1, "}\\w+).*$"),"\\1", string_col)]
Warning message:
In gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", first_n_words - 1, "}\\w+).*$"),  :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
>## This is not the desired output    
> DT 
                string_col first_n_words output_string_col
    1:            A BB CCC             2              A BB
    2:     DD EEE FFFF GDG             3            DD EEE
    3: AB DFD EFGD ABC DBC             3            AB DFD
    4:             ABC DEF             1           ABC DEF
```

This is not the desired output

Comment: What is wrong with your current approach?

Comment: I use lapply and it doesn't change the first_n_words in the function, so all entries end up with one static first_n_words (from the first row)

Comment: I do not think `gsub` is vectorized in pattern but only in `x`

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen  it doesn't work. I get warning message. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An answer to keep your use of data.table is to use a grouping operation, as you need a value in gsub, not a vector:

```
DT[,line := .I]
DT[, output_string_col := gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", first_n_words - 1, "}\\w+).*$"),"\\1", string_col),by = line]

> DT
            string_col first_n_words line output_string_col
1:            A BB CCC             2    1              A BB
2:     DD EEE FFFF GDG             3    2       DD EEE FFFF
3: AB DFD EFGD ABC DBC             3    3       AB DFD EFGD
4:             ABC DEF             1    4               ABC
```

### Edit

As @Franck remarqued the grouping should be on `first_n_words`to be more efficient

```
DT[, output_string_col := gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", first_n_words[1] - 1, "}\\w+).*$"),"\\1", string_col),by = first_n_words]
```

the benchmark with this modified version gives faster results :

```
library(microbenchmark)

denis <- function(x){
  x[, output_string_col := gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", first_n_words[1] - 1, "}\\w+).*$"),"\\1", string_col),by = first_n_words]
}



Tim <- function(x){
  x[, output_string_col := apply(x, 1, function(x) {
    gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", as.numeric(x[2]) - 1, "}\\w+).*$"), "\\1", x[1])
  })]
}

miss <- function(x){
  x[, output_string_col := stringr::word(string_col, end = first_n_words)]
}

DT <- DT[sample(1:4, 1000, replace = TRUE),]

microbenchmark(
  Tim(DT),
  miss(DT),
  denis(DT)
)

Unit: milliseconds
      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq
   Tim(DT) 56.851716 57.836126 60.435164 58.714486 60.753051
  miss(DT) 11.042056 11.516928 12.427029 11.871800 12.617031
 denis(DT)  1.993437  2.355283  2.555936  2.615181  2.680001
        max neval
 111.169277   100
  20.916932   100
   3.530668   100
```

Comment: ah, that's what my solution was missing. Thanks so much!

Comment: The pattern only varies with first_n_words, not with line... should be considerably more efficient to group on the former when many rows are involved, I guess.

Comment: Perhaps a speed benchmark using a bigger data set: `DT <- DT[sample(1:4, 100000, replace = TRUE),]`. This will vary with `length(unique(first_n_words))` also

Comment: @missuse agree, but I didn't have the time. I ll do later

Answer (score 3):

A possible approach is:

```
stringr::word(DT$string_col, end = DT$first_n_words)
#output
[1] "A BB"        "DD EEE FFFF" "AB DFD EFGD" "ABC"
```

Here is a speed comparison on this small data set:

```
library(microbenchmark)

denis <- function(x){
  x[,line := .I]
  x[, output_string_col := gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", first_n_words - 1, "}\\w+).*$"),"\\1", string_col),
    by = line]
  x[,("line") := NULL]
}



Tim <- function(x){
  x[, output_string_col := apply(x, 1, function(x) {
    gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", as.numeric(x[2]) - 1, "}\\w+).*$"), "\\1", x[1])
  })]
}

miss <- function(x){
  x[, output_string_col := stringr::word(string_col, end = first_n_words)]
}

microbenchmark(
  Tim(DT),
  miss(DT),
  denis(DT)
)
Unit: milliseconds
      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
   Tim(DT) 1.875036 1.926662 2.174488 1.971941 2.181196 12.83158   100  a 
  miss(DT) 1.452720 1.484245 1.710604 1.510905 1.592787 15.27196   100  a 
 denis(DT) 2.780183 2.864604 3.255014 2.948813 3.126542 18.78252   100   b
```

on a bigger data set:

```
DT <- DT[sample(1:4, 100000, replace = TRUE),]

    Unit: seconds
      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
   Tim(DT) 13.924312 14.628571 15.030614 14.810397 15.840749 15.949039     5   b
  miss(DT)  3.571372  3.939229  4.150258  4.237873  4.492383  4.510435     5  a 
 denis(DT) 11.291374 11.728155 13.362248 12.738197 13.478435 17.575077     5   b
```

As suggested in the comments by G. Grothendieck microbenchmark might not be the most correct way to measure performance of data table since DT is changed from one iteration to the next without resetting it to the initial value.

So in the next few lines performance will be measured just once after creation of the data table

```
DT <- data.table(string_col = c("A BB CCC",
                                "DD EEE FFFF GDG",
                                "AB DFD EFGD ABC DBC",
                                "ABC DEF"), 
                 first_n_words = c(2, 3, 3, 1))
set.seed(1)

ind <- sample(1:4, 100000, replace = TRUE)
DT1 <- DT[ind,]
system.time(Tim(DT1))
#output
   user  system elapsed 
  14.06    0.02   15.01 

DT2 <- DT[ind,]
system.time(miss(DT2))
#output
   user  system elapsed 
   2.82    0.00    2.87    

DT3 <- DT[ind,]
system.time(denis(DT3))    
#output
   user  system elapsed 
  11.56    0.03   11.98  


all.equal(DT1, DT2)
all.equal(DT2, DT3)
```

Comment: any gsub solution?

Comment: I am pretty sure no solutions with gsub will be faster than this one for the current problem since all of the require some sort of loop.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen yes Tim it did, I would have commented if I found something peculiar.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison, no doubt your solution is way faster

Comment: The benchmark needs to be fixed since (1) DT is changed from one iteration to the next without resetting it to the initial value and (2) the different alternatives don't return the same result.

Comment: I have fixed problem (2), problem (1) is harder to fix using `microbenchmark` since resetting the data table also takes time - to account for this I have added a `system.time` approach

Comment: The modified version of my answer gives the best results now.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `apply` in row mode:

```
apply(DT[, c('string_col', 'first_n_words')], 1, function(x) {
    gsub(paste0("^((\\w+\\W+){", x[1] - 1, "}\\w+).*$"), "\\1", x[0])
})
```